# How to process *.doc and *.docx file structure with docx.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, docx

I'm working on a sort of project where I need to be able to modify *.doc and *.docx documents. Working with [docx.js](https://docx.js.org/api/), a powerful Node.js tool for generating docx files, is pretty much clear to me, save for how to make it possible to read a document (template file) to be able to generate a dynamic docx file in the output, putting some dynamic data into the loaded template file and then saving it on the server.

Thanks for any clarity on that.

Comment: Looks like it's not yet supported/working: https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx/issues/489

Comment: @jonrsharpe it would be nice to get at least the way to restructurize the file manually in docx.js

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, but it's probably better aimed at the package maintainers rather than SO.